# Ruby on Rails: how to replace "puts 'foo bar' " with "<%= "foo bar" %>" in view from a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, recursion, data-structures

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and now I have come across a following situation:

I have a Category model where it could recursively have multiple subcategory nodes. I want to firstly print all of their name with indentations.

I have already written a category helper and achieved the result I wanted.

```
module CategoriesHelper

  def recursively_render_categories_in_view(category_id, index)
    this_category = Category.find(category_id)
    if leaf_category?(category_id)
      return
    end
    this_category.subcategories.each do |category|
      puts "#{' '*index*5} #{category.name}!!!!!"
      puts "#{' '*index*5} Click me to add a new category in this level!"
      recursively_render_categories_in_view(category.id, index + 1)
    end
  end

  def leaf_category?(category_id)
    Category.find(category_id).subcategories.empty?
  end

end
```

I have created a sample category tree in the db where every category only have one subcategory node and it is essentially a linked list. Using my helper above, it prints out in the console like this:

[image: result of the helper]

But how do I apply this mechanism in the view? Obviously I can't use "puts" anymore and I don't think <%=  %> can be used in the helper either. Hope I'm doing it right..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not do multiple queries for this. The performance will be awful. Do a single query to get all of the records (how will depend on your database—[here's a guide for PostgreSQL](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord)) and then render the records as nested unordered lists with `tag` or `tag_for`.

Comment: @Jordan Thank you very much for your link. I understand it could have some performance issue but I think I can only handle as much as recursion in my current level. I'll check your link again when I get better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build up the result as a single string and return that.

One way of doing this is to add an extra accumulator parameter to your method, that starts off as the empty string. Instead of using puts you append to that accumulator.

You could do something along the lines of

```
def recursively_render_categories(category, index, result = "")
  unless leaf_category?(category)
    result.subcategories.each do |category|
       result << ...
       recursively_render_categories(category, index + 1, result)
    end
  end
  result
end
```